# How to updated individaul value of a nested object in react using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a nested object in my state and on first render I am updating it's value. I want to update the values of individaul input boxes by entering any number and on clicking update button the entered values should be displaying instead of old values

Here is codesandbox link of my code : https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ardinghelli-05h0vz?file=/src/App.js:0-4109

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [insightsData, setInsightsData] = useState(
    {
    LeadtimePhysicalConstraints: { min: null, max: null },
    LeadtimeMgmntConstraints: { min: null, max: null },
    RFIReviewResponse: { min: null, max: null },
    ChangeOrderIssueReview: { min: null, max: null }
  }
  );

  const apiResponse = [    {
    LeadtimePhysicalConstraints: { min: null, max: null },
    LeadtimeMgmntConstraints: { min: 3, max: 5 },
    RFIReviewResponse: { min: 6, max: 10 },
    ChangeOrderIssueReview: { min: 8, max: 11 }
  }]

  useEffect(()=>{
    setInsightsData(apiResponse[0])
  },[])

  const handleInsightsChange=(e)=>{
    console.log("e.target",e.target.name,e.target.value)
    console.log("e",e)
  setInsightsData(prevState=>{
    return{
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    }
  })
  }

  const updateInsights=(e)=>{

  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <h3> Insights Settings Metadata</h3>
        <div className="constraint-info">
          <div className="input-area">
            <label className="label">Physical constraint: </label>
            <div className="input-boxes">
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.LeadtimePhysicalConstraints.min}
                placeholder="min"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="min"
              />
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.LeadtimePhysicalConstraints.max}
                placeholder="max"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="max"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="input-area">
            <label className="label">LeadtimeMgmnt constraint: </label>
            <div className="input-boxes">
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.LeadtimeMgmntConstraints.min}
                placeholder="min"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="min"
              />
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.LeadtimeMgmntConstraints.max}
                placeholder="max"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="max"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="input-area">
            <label className="label">RFIReviewResponse: </label>
            <div className="input-boxes">
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.RFIReviewResponse.min}
                placeholder="min"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="min"
              />
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.RFIReviewResponse.max}
                placeholder="max"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="max"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="input-area">
            <label className="label">ChangeOrderIssueReview constraint: </label>
            <div className="input-boxes">
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.ChangeOrderIssueReview.min}
                placeholder="min"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="min"
              />
              <input
                className="input-box"
                value={insightsData.ChangeOrderIssueReview.max}
                placeholder="max"
                onChange={handleInsightsChange}
                name="max"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="action-btns">
            <button className="cancel-btn" onClick={updateInsights}>Cancel</button>
            <button className="update-btn">Update</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The idea its to change the values while typing but only update them when click update button and if it clicks cancel then show the prev values ?

Comment: right @MiguelHidalgo

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, working with what you already have, you can pass the `insightsData` key to the `handleInsightsChange` function, here is how you can do that:

Change your `input`s to something like this:

```
<input
  className="input-box"
  value={insightsData.LeadtimePhysicalConstraints.min}
  placeholder="min"
  onChange={(e) => handleInsightsChange('LeadtimePhysicalConstraints', e)}
  name="min"
/>
```

And the `handleInsightsChange` function to this:

```
const handleInsightsChange = (key, e) => {
  setInsightsData(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [key]: {
      ...prevState[key],
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the updated data will be sent to the server so this approach may help:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [insightsData, setInsightsData] = useState({
    LeadtimePhysicalConstraints: {
      prev: { min: 10, max: 20 },
      next: { min: false, max: false }
    },
    LeadtimeMgmntConstraints: {
      prev: { min: 10, max: 20 },
      next: { min: false, max: false }
    },
    RFIReviewResponse: {
      prev: { min: 10, max: 20 },
      next: { min: false, max: false }
    },
    ChangeOrderIssueReview: {
      prev: { min: 10, max: 20 },
      next: { min: false, max: false }
    }
  });

  const options = [
    { label: "Physical constraint:", key: "LeadtimePhysicalConstraints" },
    { label: "LeadtimeMgmnt constraint:", key: "LeadtimeMgmntConstraints" },
    { label: "RFIReviewResponse:", key: "RFIReviewResponse" },
    {
      label: "ChangeOrderIssueReview constraint:",
      key: "ChangeOrderIssueReview"
    }
  ];

  const hanldeCancel = () => {
    setInsightsData((prev) => {
      Object.keys(prev).forEach((key) => {
        prev[key].next = { min: false, max: false };
      });

      return { ...prev };
    });
  };

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    const updated = {};

    Object.keys(insightsData).forEach((key) => {
      updated[key] = insightsData[key].next;
    });

    //send updated data to server...
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <h3> Insights Settings Metadata</h3>
        <div className="constraint-info">
          {options.map(({ label, key }) => (
            <div className="input-area" key={key}>
              <label className="label">{label}</label>
              <div className="input-boxes">
                <input
                  className="input-box"
                  onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                    setInsightsData((prev) => ({
                      ...prev,
                      [key]: {
                        ...prev[key],
                        next: { ...prev[key].next, min: value }
                      }
                    }))
                  }
                  value={
                    insightsData[key].next.min || insightsData[key].prev.min
                  }
                />
                <input
                  className="input-box"
                  onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                    setInsightsData((prev) => ({
                      ...prev,
                      [key]: {
                        ...prev[key],
                        next: { ...prev[key].next, max: value }
                      }
                    }))
                  }
                  value={
                    insightsData[key].next.max || insightsData[key].prev.max
                  }
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
          <div className="action-btns">
            <button className="cancel-btn" onClick={hanldeCancel}>
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button className="update-btn" onClick={handleUpdate}>
              Update
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```